# Matrices with overloading. Can't use multiple operators

Tags: c++

I'm working on matrices with overloading. When using only one operator (+) code works fine, but when I try do add (-) or (*), errot that appears to be allocation problem appears.

"Unhandled exception at 0x00077E3B in Overload.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

In class:

```
Macierz::Macierz(int a,int b)    // Matrix
{
    Alokacja();              // Allocate
}

Macierz::Macierz(const Macierz& a_mac) : m(a_mac.m), n(a_mac.n)
{
    Alokacja();
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            macierz[i][j] = a_mac.macierz[i][j];
        }
    }
}


void Macierz::Jedynki()        // Matrix::Ones
{
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        macierz [i][j]=1;
        }
    }
}

void Macierz::Wyswietl()        // Matrix::Display
{
        for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cout <<macierz[i][j]<<"\t";
            cout <<endl;
        }
}

Macierz Macierz::operator +(const Macierz & mac)
{    
    Macierz tmp(mac);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        mac.macierz[i][j]=macierz[i][j]+mac.macierz[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tmp; 

}
Macierz Macierz::operator *(const Macierz & mac)

{
    Macierz tmp(mac);
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            mac.macierz[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k<n; k++)
            {
                mac.macierz[i][j] += macierz[i][k] * mac.macierz[k][j];

            }

        }
        return tmp;

    }
}




void Macierz::Alokacja()
{
    macierz=new double*[m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        macierz[i]= new double[n];
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
Macierz::~Macierz()
{
        for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
            delete []macierz[i];
            delete []macierz;
}
```

In main.cpp:

```
cout<<"macierze"<<endl;       // "matrices"

Macierz i(2,2);
Macierz j(2,2);
Macierz k(2,2);   
Macierz macierz(2,2);

macierz.Wyswietl();

    i.Jedynki();
    j.Jedynki();
    k.Jedynki();
    (i+j).Wyswietl();


cout << "A tu przemnozona" << endl;   // "and here is multiplied"


    (i*j).Wyswietl();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In header:

```
class Macierz            // Matrix
{
public:
    int m, n;
    double **macierz;


    Macierz(int a, int b);
    Macierz(const Macierz&);

    void Alokacja();    // Allocate
    void Jedynki();     // Ones
    void Wyswietl();    // Display
    Macierz  operator +(const Macierz&  mac);
    Macierz  operator *(const Macierz&  mac);
    ~Macierz(void);
};
```

Comment: My answer is: You don't. Instead you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Also, it's the first time I've ever seen `-` used for *adding*... Please edit your question to the correct operators.

Comment: My Polish is non-existent. Any chance this could be done in English?

Comment: @WhozCraig: `operator+(); public; clsMyClass; class;`

Comment: The problem is, most likely, that you don't follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (or the [rule of zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html)).

Comment: @WhozCraig Added some Polish-to-English hints (didn't want to translate the whole code)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your *operator+* doesn't seem to work either.

When a temporary *tmp* object created here:

```
Macierz tmp(mac);
```

lives on stack and later, when the function is finished, it's destructor is called, which kills all the heap allocated elements. And more, it also kills the argument's data as it's member *macierz* points to the same memory block as the temporary object.

Regards

deep ctor:

in header:

```
Macierz(const Macierz&);
```

in body:

```
Macierz::Macierz(const Macierz& a_mac) : m(a_mac.m),n(a_mac.n)
{
  Alokacja();
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++) {
        macierz[i][j] = a_mac.macierz[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've forgot 
Macierz::Macierz(int a, int b) : m(a), n(b).

Comment: @Nars it is true, but that doesn't matter. In body of *operator+* you create an object *tmp* by calling *copy constructor*, which doesn't make any kind of deep copy.

Comment: What do I need to change to make all my operators working then?

Comment: What do I need to change to make all my operators working then? I've kindoff made it work by replacing tmp(mac) with mac1, and deleting "&", so i don't work at copy... Program runs, but not correctly (VS tells me to break it, continue doesn't work).

Comment: @Nars if you do want/need to work with row pointers, implementing a copy constructor with deep copy may help.

Comment: It tells me that it cannot define a compiler-generated special member function.

Comment: @Nars did you put declaration in header file? Make sure you defined it only once

Comment: Ok now I only get this...: Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Macierz::Macierz(int,int)" (??0Macierz@@QAE@HH@Z) C:\Users\Bohun\Downloads\Projekt_macierze(2)\Projekt_macierze\Projekt_macierze\Main.obj Projektnumer1

Comment: @Nars just make sure the singnature of declaration and definition are the same. I've put declation in the answer. AND, it looks like you forgot to put definition of Macierz::Macierz(int,int) inside .cpp

Comment: Thanks for so much help! I've updated a question to show how it looks like now. Program runs, but with location problems: Unhandled exception at 0x00147E3B in Overload.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @Nars no worries, but you have two special construcotrs with the same singature now. That is bad

Comment: Macierz::Macierz(int,int)    and    Macierz::Macierz(const Macierz& a_mac) : m(a_mac.m), n(a_mac.n)  ?

Comment: Also, do I need destructor for both of them now?

Comment: @Nars you have this: Macierz::Macierz(int,int)   and you have this Macierz::Macierz(int a, int b). Those are the same and that's wrong. Destructor is unique, there can't be more then one

Comment: But can I have two constructors?

Comment: @Nars of course you can and you do have. You can have a default ctor, a copy ctor, many special ctors (singnatures must differ) and also a move ctor.

Comment: VS expects int from deep ctor if I change signature on it.

Comment: @Nars don't change the deep copy ctor. Look at your special ctors and keep Macierz::Macierz(int a, int b) only.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for this, I didn't realised that i left it here. However, I didn't had this in project for ages. And now, program runs without problems, but I don't get any results (blank when matrices should be).

Comment: @Nars debug it and you'll find out :)

Comment: After adding "*" allocation error again, like at the beggining. How do  I use deep constructor with it?

Comment: @Nars alright, what do you think about this Macierz macierz(-1,0); ? How do you imagine a matrix with "-1" rows?